# The "count" and "for_each" meta-arguments are mutually-exclusive, only one should be used to be explicit about the number of resources to be created

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Resource code:

```
resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "kinesis_firehose_to_s3" { 
    count = "${var.fh_destination == s3 ? 1 : 0}" 
    for_each = {for entity in var.entities : entity.name => entity} 
    name = test_firehose
}
```

Issue: I am not able to use the combination of both the below syntax in creating the terraform resource.. but separately working.

```
count = "${var.fh_destination == s3 ? 1 : 0}" 
for_each = {for entity in var.entities : entity.name => entity}
```

Requirements:

1. It has to create this `kinesis_firehose_to_s3` resource only when `fh_destination`= s3

```
count = "${var.fh_destination == s3 ? 1 : 0}
```

2. It has to create this resource for each entity:

```
for_each = { for entity in var.entities : entity.name => entity}
```

Comment: Sorry it is count not condition...

Answer (score 5):

I assume in your question when you said `condition` you really meant `count`, because `condition` is not a resource meta-argument in Terraform.

In your `count` expression you are choosing between having one instance or having zero instances based on some condition. In `for_each` we declare how many instances we want by changing how many elements there are in the `for_each` map, so the equivalent in `for_each` would be to choose between an empty map or a non-empty map depending on the same condition.

For example:

```
  for_each = (
    var.fh_destination == "s3" ?
    { for entity in var.entities : entity.name => entity } :
    {}
  )
```

With the above conditional expression, if `var.fh_destination == "s3"` then the result will have one element per element of `var.entities`, but otherwise the result will have zero elements and thus zero instances, creating the same result as the `0` arm of your conditional `count`.